# is it possible to start a private chain from a specific height?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am running a private chain with a height of 4,80,000. Now I want to change the reward rules and other configurations.

If I build geth with new parameters, the new executable will not recognize the old datadir and chain starts with `eth.blockNumber` = 0;

So for this,I want to start from blockNumber 4,80,001, i.e. don't want to lose the blockheight. (however, I have planned to find balances of all the accounts on the nodes and start with pre-allocated amount to those balances).

Is it possible?
Can I start from a specific height?